# Get All orders using rest API with specific feilds

Tags: orders, rest-api, column

I am using this

> `http://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders/7??fields=billing_address,customer_firstname,customer_lastname`

it return the billing_address,customer_firstname,customer_lastname of order id 7, I want to get these details of all orders so i try

> `http://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria=all`

it work return all orders But i want to get specific feilds for example billing_address,customer_firstname,customer_lastname.

How can I get specifics columns of all orders?

Comment: Can you please add proper tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one, the response will have only these fields.

`entity_id, billing_address,customer_firstname, and customer_lastname` only

```
http://www.domain.com/rest/V1/orders?
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=entity_id&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=1&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=gteq&
searchCriteria[sortOrders][0][field]=increment_id&
fields=items[entity_id,billing_address,customer_firstname,customer_lastname]
```

[check link for a detailed guide](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/rest/performing-searches.html#example-for-search-criteria-to-determine-the-sort-order-and-attributes-to-return)